# Scroll to a particular section triggering from different component angular 4

Tags: angular, angular5

In my angular 4 project I have a component of menu section. This menu section consists of menus and submenus and my another component is details section of this menus.

I want to when I am clicking the menus from the menu section the details menu section will be scrolled to the desired section smoothly without affecting the URL(not appending hash tags).

Here is the screen shot of this two components(1. menucomponent, 2. detailcomponent)

menucomponent screenshot:

[image]

I am providing menu section code:
Detailcomponent screenshot:-

[image]

```
<div class="rsnt-cat-menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Popular</a></li>
            <li class="active-cat" *ngFor="let menu of menuArray">

                <a href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="gotoTop();">{{ menu.cat_name }}</a>
                <ul>
                    <li *ngFor="let submenumenu of menu.sub_category_list">
                        <a href="">{{ submenumenu.cat_name }}</a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

details section code

```
<div *ngFor="let singleElement of foodArray" class="rsnt-menu-block">
        <h2 class="main-subheading">{{ singleElement.cat_name }}</h2>
        <div *ngFor="let subchildElement of singleElement.sub_category_list">
            <div>
                <h3 
                    class="main-subheading-type2">
                    {{ subchildElement.cat_name }} {{ subchildElement.sub_category_item.length }} Items
                </h3>
                <div>
                    <ul *ngFor="let sibling of subchildElement.sub_category_item" class="menu-row-list">

                        <li *ngIf="sibling.filterStatus">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-9">
                                    <h5><span [ngClass]="{'ft-nonveg' : sibling.item_veg== '0' , 'ft-veg' : sibling.item_veg== '1' }" class="food-type"></span> 
                                    {{ sibling.item_name }}</h5>
                                    <span class="item-main-price">{{ sibling.sales_price }}</span>
                                    <span class="sub-head-type1">{{ sibling.item_desc }}</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-3">
                                    <div class="cart-action">
                                        <button class="add-cart" type="button">ADD</button>
                                        <div class="cart-i-q">
                                            <input readonly="" value="1" type="text">
                                            <button disabled="" type="button" class="add-i-b valdown">-</button>
                                            <button type="button" class="add-i-b valup">+</button>
                                        </div>
                                        <span *ngIf="sibling.choice" class="customised-txt">Customisable</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>                                            
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="singleElement.sub_category_list.length==0">
            <span>{{ singleElement.category_item.length }} Items</span>
            <ul *ngFor="let catchildElement of singleElement.category_item" class="menu-row-list">
                    <li *ngIf="catchildElement.filterStatus">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-9">
                                <h5><span [ngClass]="{'ft-nonveg' : catchildElement.item_veg== '0' , 'ft-veg' : catchildElement.item_veg== '1' }" class="food-type"></span> 
                                {{ catchildElement.item_name }}</h5>
                                <span class="item-main-price">{{ catchildElement.sales_price }}</span>
                                <span class="sub-head-type1">{{ catchildElement.item_desc }}</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-3">
                                <div class="cart-action">
                                    <button class="add-cart" type="button">ADD</button>
                                    <div class="cart-i-q">
                                        <input readonly="" value="1" type="text">
                                        <button disabled="" type="button" class="add-i-b valdown">-</button>
                                        <button type="button" class="add-i-b valup">+</button>
                                    </div>
                                    <span *ngIf="catchildElement.choice" class="customised-txt">Customisable</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>                                            
                    </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

See if you can use this module to do the scroll without route change, https://github.com/nicky-lenaers/ngx-scroll-to, works for me in the past.